# How convert image's to black and white? (with scipy or matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I need to take this image and rotate it 90d and print it in black and white colors.
I need to do it with matplotlib or scipy.

```py
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

face = scipy.misc.face()
rotate = ndimage.rotate(face,90)
gray = rotate
plt.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

I saw this code in few websites but the image it only rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
image = Image.open("convert.png")
image = image_file.convert('1')
image = image.rotate(90)
image.save('result.png')
```

Comment: I saw this solution but my teacher asked me to do it with scipy or matplotlib

Comment: @importanceofbeingernest closed your question and has attached the answer of your question in another topic, good luck!